# Check if a user is logged in using default login form or using email direct login link

Tags: 8, users

I'm working on a Drupal 8 project, my question is:

is there any method to check if a user is logged in using email direct link or he did using the default site login form?

to check I think the right hook is `hook_user_login($account)`

```
function mymodule_user_login($account) {
  // if user logged in from direct link.
    dump('Hey where were you?');
  // if user logged in from default login form.
    dump('Yeah, nice login dude')
}
```

Comment: Did you try using \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() to check current route name?

Comment: thanks dude, when user logged in from default login form the route name is `user.login` and other situation (case email link to change password) the route name is `user.reset.login`. Thanks now I can control the situation :)